# Is there a bundled library available in ReactJs which we can include in any websites and utilize the ReactJs Components

Tags: reactjs

Is there any ReactJs library available which i can include in my website and start write react components, similar to jQuery, without using any extra libraries (i.e Node modules)

Answer (score 0):

Add these scripts to your `.html`:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Comment: I hope this will help only for the simple components, but whether this will help when you go for the complex components which has dependency with node modules like css_loader, etc..?

Comment: I'm confused then, you asked if there was a way to use react "without using any extra libraries (i.e Node modules)"

Comment: I mean without using any extra libraries in my web application, even though the component built using different node modules.  And whether react.js and react-dom.js would be enough for any type of components built in ReactJs?

Comment: [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) is how to add React to your website. You can use as little or as much as you'd like. You don't have to install any extra libraries. React.js and react-dom will be enough